# How to download a CRX file from the Chrome web store for a given ID?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, chrome-web-store

I'd like to download the .crx file of an extension from webstore, I use fiddler to analyze the network request when I install an extension from webstore and got it.
For example, for the extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bjclhonkhgkidmlkghlkiffhoikhaajg
the download link is:

https://clients2.googleusercontent.com/crx/download/OgAAADQ_Loe5gfVPF2OUaB35tvex-NKlmA8V4K5YlWuvLCknMH7egLLmnMoFuCZePl_idE1GMf8jZC2KbjQqyyLDoDAAxlKa5eDp-z9frOppHWtQsRU3-iGrrrrA/extension_1_7_11.crx
Now I'm wondering if there is a universal method for get .crx of an extension, the problem is how did Google encryption

`bjclhonkhgkidmlkghlkiffhoikhaajg`

into

`OgAAADQ_Loe5gfVPF2OUaB35tvex-NKlmA8V4K5YlWuvLCknMH7egLLmnMoFuCZePl_idE1GMf8jZC2KbjQqyyLDoDAAxlKa5eDp-z9frOppHWtQsRU3-iGrrrrA` ?

any idea will be helpful.

Comment: For all we know they could easily just be two random numbers stored in a database somewhere with no actual mapping. Why do you want this - you want to scrape all the extensions off the site mechanically?

Comment: You can also use 'Give Me CRX', a Google Chrome extension for obtaining source .crx file of any Chrome extension via its Web Store. P.S: I created and published this extension. Extension link: [Give Me CRX (a Chrome Extension)](http://goo.gl/LT98O)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

For one of my extensions I had to download other CRXs automatically knowing only extension ID. I solved this by opening the following URL:

```
http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D<EXTENSION_ID_HERE>%26uc%26lang%3Den-US&prod=chrome
```

this page will forward you to that `https://clients2.googleusercontent.com/crx/download/` address.

I don't remember already how I came up with that URL (it was either in page source somewhere or I used network sniffer), but it has been working great for me since last December, so it looks reliable.

Comment: Oh you are the developer of "Extension Gallery and Web Store Inspector"? thanks very much!

Comment: This will work perfectly for an install link on my website. Thanks a lot! It's worth noting that you get the warning notification when using this URL. Is this the same when using it within an extension?

Comment: @Alasdair Warning is probably displayed when you are trying to install in, not just download.

Comment: It seems like Google has changed something recently and this approach no longer works (it returns 204). Anyone have any idea what changed? The author of chrome-extension-downloader.com appears to have fixed it but hasn't updated the documentation.

Comment: The long URL provided in the question still works, though. So back to square one!

Comment: No longer works. I get `204 No Content`. Even after replacing `%3D` with  `=` and `%26` with `&`.

Comment: Confirming that this URL no longer works, I get `204 No Content` too. **See the answer mentioning PRODVERSION, that one works.**

Comment: Here's the one I use that works for native and non-native extensions: `https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&os=linux&arch=x86-64&nacl_arch=x86-64&prod=chromiumcrx&prodchannel=unknown&prodversion=49.0.2623.108&x=id%3D{ID}%26uc` with `{ID}` being the extension id.

Comment: That last one doesn't seem to work either

Answer (score 156):

The CRX file itself can be directly downloaded from
`https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=[PRODVERSION]&acceptformat=crx2,crx3&x=id%3D[EXTENSIONID]%26uc`

- [PRODVERSION] is the version of Chrome, which must be 31.0.1609.0 **at the very least**, and
- [EXTENSIONID] is the ID of the extension

**(New in 2018)** `acceptformat=crx2,crx3` instructs the server to also respond with extensions in [the CRX3 format](https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/issues/62) (instead of 204 No Content when the extension is not available as CRX2).

If the extension you're using contains OS-specific modules (e.g. NaCl), then you have to add additional parameters (`os`, `arch`, `nacl_arch`).

For the full logic of generating a complete CRX download URL, see the `get_crx_url` function in https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/blob/master/src/cws_pattern.js.

This is a part of the Chrome Extension Source Viewer extension, available in the Chrome Web Store: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin

---

Note that opening the previous URL in Chrome will **not** trigger a download because Chrome automatically intercepts responses whose `Content-Type` is set to `application/x-chrome-extension`. If you want to programatically download the crx file in a Chrome extension, change the MIME-type to `application/octet-stream` (e.g. as done in [`src/lib/crx-to-zip.js`](https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/blob/master/src/lib/crx-to-zip.js)).

Comment: Note: Some extensions contain NaCl modules, that require additional query string parameters. See the source code of my crxviewer extension for the composition of the URL: https://github.com/Rob--W/crxviewer/commit/49a84243c9dadfd0401955a4c839bcc13ad53ce9

Comment: Chrome threw a fit while trying to open this url, if you are on windows, then open it in IE to download it with no problem.

Comment: @craastad Because Chrome recognizes the file as an extension. Install the [Chrome extension source viewer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) to easily access the extension's source code in Chrome/Opera.

Comment: God bless you, internet stranger. This works at the time of this comment.

The older url that I had was working only for some urls, but not all. This one solved it :D

Comment: This can be used to install Themes in Microsoft Edge (Chromium) without having to trust a third-party website or extension to acquire the CRX for you; just punch the URL as specified directly into the address bar and Edge does the rest.

Comment: Example URL that worked for me: https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=95.0.4638.54&acceptformat=crx2,crx3&x=id%3Dpnlccmojcmeohlpggmfnbbiapkmbliob%26uc

Comment: For those looking to download the CRX file from the Microsoft Extension store, use `https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D[EXTENSIONID]%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc` instead.

Comment: To download with curl: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665097/how-can-i-download-a-chrome-extension-using-curl/19665274#19665274

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a small python script to automate that process what @serg @Rob W

https://gist.github.com/arulrajnet/2424bc1ffc40324f3786

you can use that also.

```
python ChromeAppDownloader.py -u https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-maps/lneaknkopdijkpnocmklfnjbeapigfbh
```

This is how you have to use.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the below URL template,

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=[PRODVERSION]&x=id%3D[EXTENSIONID]%26uc
```

The **PRODVERSION** is the Chrome version. (get it from settings -> Help -> About Google Chrome).
Ex : Version `69.0.3497.100` (Official Build) (64-bit)

The **EXTENSIONID** is the id for the extension. 
Ex : Here is a sample plugin, https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji?hl=en the id is `hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji`

So sample request to download will be https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=69.0.3497.100&x=id%3Dhmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji%26uc

Answer (score 6):

Another way to get the crx file.

1. Copy the url of the extension, for example:
   https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tiff-viewer/fciggfkkblggmebjbekbebbcffeacknj?hl=es
2. In the website http://crxextractor.com/
3. Click in the option "START FOR FREE".
4. Paste the url of the extension in the textbox.
5. Click in the option "DOWNLOAD".
6. Click in the option "GET .CRX".

Answer (score 3):

This is a lower-tech way of doing it than to use fiddler, and I realize this is three years old now, but I always look to see if someone else has solved the problem.  So I found someone did, and I just used their solution several times successfully.  Their solution is an extension that can download other extensions, called Give Me CRX:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/give-me-crx/acpimoebmfjpfnbhjgdgiacjfebmmmci

Answer (score 3):

Also, I recommend to try this website http://crxextractor.com.
Here you can download an extension by it's Chrome Webstore URL and extract it's source code in the browser, no additional software required, and everything get done in a click or two.

Comment: Chrome blocks the download without giving me a option to keep the file other than the discard button. How to work around this?

Answer (score 3):

To download the chrome extension from a given id, you could just use like this

```
var currentEXTId = 'bjclhonkhgkidmlkghlkiffhoikhaajg';    
let downloadURL = https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D" + currentEXTId + "%26uc&prodversion=32;
```

The above one is the download URL for the chrome extension. 
There is also a chrome extension which could help you for downloading chrome extension as zip or crx file.https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/crx-extractordownloader/ajkhmmldknmfjnmeedkbkkojgobmljda

Also the code for how its done is available in this [Github repo](https://github.com/dashokkumar93/crx-download)

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Answer (score 2):

Create a bookmark add the javascript function as the address. 
Browse to the chrome extension you want to download then click on the bookmark and it should start downloading.

```
javascript:(function(){
    var pathname = location.pathname;pathArray = pathname.split("/");   
    location = ("http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id"+"%" + "3D" + pathArray[pathArray.length -1]+"%" + "26uc%" + "26lang%" + "3Den-US&prod=chrome"); })();
```

Thanks

Comment: @adardesign Have you tried it? This does not even work, for two reasons: 1. Use `location.pathname` instead of `location.href`. If the URL contains `?lang=en`, then this snippet will fail. 2. Chrome will not "start downloading", but ask you to install the extension.

Comment: You are right, I was just trying to answer this question with the following gist, but then  I saw this answer, where the same idea was put into a bookmarklet.. and no I didn't try it. See gist.. https://gist.github.com/adardesign/c0dff591556b90fefcc5

Comment: `location.href = 'http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=42&x=' + encodeURIComponent('uc&id=' + location.pathname.split('/').pop());`

Comment: this workes for me `javascript:(function(){ location.href = 'https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=38.0&x=' + encodeURIComponent('id=' + location.pathname.split('/').pop() + '%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc'); })();`

Comment: My version: `javascript:window.location.href=%22https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=95&acceptformat=crx2,crx3&x=id%253D%22+window.location.href.split(%27/%27).at(-1).split(%27?%27)[0]+%22%2526uc%22 `using auto-escape

Answer (score 2):

This works for Microsoft Edge Chromium:

```
https://edge.microsoft.com/extensionwebstorebase/v1/crx?response=redirect&prod=chromiumcrx&prodchannel=&x=id%3D<EXTENSION_ID_HERE>%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc
```

Answer (score 2):

I made a simple [Python script](https://github.com/sryze/crx-dl) for downloading extensions as CRX files from the Chrome Web Store:

It has no external dependencies and works with either Python 2 or 3.

Thanks to [Rob W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099762/249230) for the original solution.

Answer (score 1):

None of the manually ways in this post works for me so i searched for a URL to download the extension direct.
Find this and works perfect for me.

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=49.0&x=id%3D###EXTENSION_ID###%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc
```

You must replace ###EXTENSION_ID### with the extension id from the chrome shop.
Its part of the URL.

Example Google Translate Extension:

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=49.0&x=id%3Daapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb%26installsource%3Dondemand%26uc
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the https://www.crx4chrome.com/ and search for your extension, it also has a different version of that extension, once you click it download .crx file