# Is there an easy way to unpack a Chrome extension in the Chrome Web store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Is there an easy way to view the source code of a chrome extension without having to install it?

There is no crx file, just the usual webstore url with the long string of random characters at the end.

Answer (score 21):

Install [Chrome extension source viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) to get a button at the Chrome Web store. This button allows you to download the extension in a zip file.
It also offers a built-in source viewer, so you don't have to extract the files yourself.

Screenshot:
[image: Chrome Web store: (Download as zip) (View source)]

Disclaimer: I wrote the extension.
If you want a bookmarklet which generates a wget command, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14099762/938089?how-to-download-a-crx-file-from-the-chrome-web-store-for-a-given-id).