# How can I download a Chrome extension using curl?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Given the ID of a Chrome extension, what's the URL to download it using curl?

Comment: Related: [How to download a CRX file from the Chrome web store for a given ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14099762/938089) (the answer shows a method using `wget` though)

Comment: @RobW - good find. The main issue is being able to hit the right URL from the command line; which command is used is no big deal.

Answer (score 4):

This works for me.

```
ID=lkajd9lk32093lkdd93lkd # replace with target extension's id in the store
URL="https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D$ID%26uc"

# -L to handle any redirects
curl -L "$URL" > some_file.crx
```

Note that the `.crx` file can be unpacked with `unzip`.

Comment: Note that the `.crx` file can be unpacked with `unzip`