# troubleshoot google api to download crx from webstore

Tags: chrome-web-store

I am trying the following google api to download extensions(.crx files) from google webstore but the api is not returning the .crx file.
Also it doesn't throw any error. On checking the webstore link for the extension, the extension is available and valid (checked by installing).

Issue with: https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dbbplcobgoobcpidocgedbkoejegpkeam%26uc

using it with curl: curl -L -o extension.crx https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dbbplcobgoobcpidocgedbkoejegpkeam%26uc

Can anybody help me with inputs to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download a CRX file from the Chrome web store for a given ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184793/how-to-download-a-crx-file-from-the-chrome-web-store-for-a-given-id)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184793/how-to-download-a-crx-file-from-the-chrome-web-store-for-a-given-id/14099762#14099762

Answer (score 1):

Chrome webstore has updated its API for extensions downloading. Here is latest usage pattern (2nd August 2014):

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D(EXT-ID-HERE)%26uc&prodversion=32
```

And here is an example:

```
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3Dhbdkkfheckcdppiaiabobmennhijkknn%26uc&prodversion=32
```