# How can I download a Chrome extension CRX file with the manifest in version 3 given an extension ID?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, download, chrome-web-store

I am trying to download the CRX file for the DarkReader extension with the manifest in version 3. The extension page: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dark-reader/eimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh/

Using the answers in the following question I can only obtain the manifest in version 2:
[How to download a CRX file from the Chrome web store for a given ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7184793/how-to-download-a-crx-file-from-the-chrome-web-store-for-a-given-id)

```
❯ head darkreader/manifest.json
{
"update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Dark Reader",
```

The URL I am using:
https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&prodversion=103.0.5060.53&acceptformat=crx2,crx3&x=id%3Deimadpbcbfnmbkopoojfekhnkhdbieeh%26uc

Thank you!

Comment: This extension is published as ManifestV2 so you can't download it as ManifestV3. The author of the extension will have to rewrite parts of the extension to make it compatible with ManifestV3 and then the author will publish it as ManifestV3.

Comment: Hello @wOxxOm, thank you for your reply. I see [here](https://github.com/darkreader/darkreader/releases/tag/v4.9.52) that the extension is also compiled with the version 3. I asked a question on the extension github Q&A regarding the timeline.